# R: Solve for variable for all rows, and output answer to new column

Tags: r

I have the formula: `f=b*(1-exp((-t)/x))`

f, b, and t all correspond to columns in my data frame, and I am trying to solve for x. I want to solve for x for each row in the data frame and output the answer into a new column.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
f <- df$value
t <- df$time
b <- df$initial

formula <- function(x){
     f=b*(1-exp((-t)/x))
}

df$answer <- solve(formula(x))
```

I've also tried things like:

```
apply(df[,c("answer", 1, FUN=formula)
```

I've also tried doing a Vectorize function.

But I cannot seem to get anything right.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72356195/edit) with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Do you want to find the formula's root for each triplet `(f, t, b)`, for each row?